# jQuery draggable + droppable - Physically move dragged item into dropped container

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I need to be able to take an element that is set as draggable and physically move that element into the container as opposed to just overlaying it as the current functionality does.

So for example:

```
 <div class="container"></div>
 <div class="image">
    <img class="thumb" src="images/Koala.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>

 $(function () {
    $(".image").draggable();
    $(".container").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert('dropped!');
        }
    });
 });
```

So after the image has been dragged and dropped into the 'container' div I need the actual html element to be moved there.

So after the event occurred, if I were to look at the source using Chrome's dev tools I would see:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="image">
        <img class="thumb" src="images/Koala.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
 </div>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You will never see JS changes to the dom in your source view. You may see the changes in the dev tools of your browser though.

Comment: Yeah that is what I meant. I will revise my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should move the dragged element to the droppable in the dom tree.

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).append(ui.draggable);
}
```

Comment: This does put it within the DOM object, but (see my example answer), the draggable is left with CSS that puts it visually outside the container.

Comment: @saluce: This depends on the CSS definitions that may already exists. Maybe the OP has a definition, that let float all images in .container, then he doesn't need to set any additional CSS.

Answer (score 3):

In the drop function, `$(this)` is the droppable accepting the draggable, so just use `.append()` to add the draggable to the droppable: http://jsfiddle.net/saluce/P6TjC/

```
$(function () {
    $(".image").draggable({helper: 'original'});
    $(".container").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).append(ui.draggable.css({position: 'static'}));
            alert('dropped!');
        }
    });
 });​
```

Comment: 'static' caused problems with continuing to drag the element. I used: $(this).append(ui.draggable.css({position: "relative", top:"", left:""}));